# Unnamed, hidden partitions on my 500 GB HD, HP Pavilion dm4 Laptop

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning, backup

I have multiple doubts here. Its a Seagate 500GB 7200RPM HD. I had installed it few months back after my original Laptop HD stopped working. The current drives on my latop, as shown by the Windows Disk Management are:

[image]

After installing the new HD, I had done a complete clean install of Windows 7 and I didn't create any parition myself, manually. So there are 4 drives. Even previously, before I installed this new HD, my laptop had 4 Partitions. But the there were no un-named partitions like the two in this case. The other two were HP tools and Recovery or something. It was pre-configured, Factory installed Windows.

Also, now when I right cick on the unnamed Drives from Disk Management, all the options are greyed out (see image) except the delete partition image.

1. So how do I know what's inside those partitions?
2. Will it be ok if I delete them?
3. I want install Ubuntu and dual boot it with my current windows installation. I cannot do it in current setup as there are already 4 partitions of my HD and if I will try to make a new partition, it will be a logical one (correct me if I am wrong here). So can I delete the un-named, hidden partitions and use them for Ubuntu?
4. A bit unrelated question. As a backup option, can I use the Windows 7's Backup and Restore facility to keep a complete backup of all the drivers and system softwares.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. *So how do I know what's inside those partitions?*

You already do: there is nothing. The fact that the amount of "free" space equals the partition capacity indicates that there is not even a filesystem installed on them.

2. *Will it be ok if I delete them?*

Sure. Then you will have a single, large, unallocated space.

3. *I want to install Ubuntu and dual boot it with my current windows installation. I cannot do it in current setup as there are already 4 partitions of my HD and if I will try to make a new partition, it will be a logical one (correct me if I am wrong here). So can I delete the un-named, hidden partitions and use them for Ubuntu?*

Right on. You will have to tell the installer program that you want to keep Windows alongside your new Ubuntu install. Then installer will proceed to format the free, unallocated space, to suit Ubuntu's needs.

After this, it may happen that your pc does not boot properly: it may be unable to see Windows, or Ubuntu, or both of them. If this happens, do not despair: re-insert the Ubuntu installation medium (a USB stick or a cd, whichever you chose), and install boot-repair: you can find [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) all of the info necessary to install it, and to run it properly. It is enough to solve most problems of this sort. Just remember that the installation medium cannot be altered, so that, if you need to repeat this boot-repair operation, on this pc or a different one, you will have to re-install the boot-repair package.

Answer (score 1):

I upvoted Marius' answer... well said. I don't have the rep to comment on it.

to answer question 4:

4. Yes, but be careful. Windows 7 Backup and Restore has two methods for performing backups: file / folders and system image. You'll need the system image for it to include windows, all of your settings, basically a snapshot of your system as it was at the time of the backup. Using the system image you can restore your system to exactly how it was.

If you only use the file/folder level backup, you'll only be backing up files, libraries and some settings (not all program files or windows). If needed, you'd be looking at a fresh install of windows and the applications and recovering data only, using the files/folder method.

Here's where to find it:  (if you don't have a system repair disc, you may want to make one now as well).

[image: system image backup]